# Regular expression not working when checking pattern for "exactly {n} number of times"

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on validation using regex but when testing it was not working as expected. 
I logged it in console but part to "match exactly n times" of the regex was not showing in console.
I don't have much knowledge about regex apart from some basic.

It will be lot of help if someone can help me with this issue.

```
var pan=$("#pan").val();

var panRegx=/^([a-zA-Z]){5}([0-9]){4}([a-zA-Z]){1}?$/

if(!panRegx.test(pan))
    {
        alert("Please provide a valid PAN no.");
        err++;
    }
```

when I logged the pattern in console I got

```
/^([a-zA-Z])([0-9])([a-zA-Z])?$/
```

instead of

```
/^([a-zA-Z]){5}([0-9]){4}([a-zA-Z]){1}?$/
```

following is the screenshot of the console

[image]

for a workaround I tried {n,n} instead of {n} and it's working for now but I still don't know what the issue is.

Comment: (OT: `{1}` is quite superfluous.)

Comment: [Test](https://regex101.com/r/CyChPN/1) it here. It works fine

Comment: i also tested it on that site and it was working but when i was running on the site it was not working

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. I did `console.log(panRegx)` and it looked exactly like it was entered.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Even I couldn't reproduce the problem.

Comment: Providing screenshot will not be helpful to solve your issue, you have to provide a minimal reproducible example as said in earlier comments so that someone can help you